# SQL Server Reverse Octets in IPv4 Address?

Tags: sql-server, string, uniqueidentifier, patindex

I have some dumps from a Microsoft TMG log table, the IP address is stored as a uniqueidentifier. I was able to convert the values into human-readable "dotted octet notation" (this is all IP v4 stuff), but the values are coming out reversed.

What is the most efficient way to reverse the values?

Thanks.

Examples:

```
Is                  ShouldBe
189.148.151.123     123.151.148.189
251.116.199.173     173.199.116.251
1.0.0.127           127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The easiest way is to reverse them before you convert them into dotted notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (ab)use [`parsename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) for that:

```
select  parsename(ip_col,4) + '.' +
        parsename(ip_col,3) + '.' +
        parsename(ip_col,2) + '.' +
        parsename(ip_col,1)
from    YourTable
```